# How does the enable.auto.commit and auto.commit.interval.ms affects offset commit in a consumer

Tags: apache-kafka

Here are my consumer settings.

```
enable.auto.commit  - true (default value)
auto.commit.interval.ms - 5000 ms (default value)
max.poll.interval.ms - 5 mins (default value)
max.poll.records - 500 (default value)
```

With those settings, let's say i get 500 records when i poll and if the consumer can process only 100 records within this 5000 ms, my question is

1. Would it commit only 100 records?
2. If yes is the answer to the above question, what happens to the other records?
3. If no is the answer for the first question, it should commit offset for all the 500 records. Then when does the 'max.poll.interval.ms' come into picture and how does this affect the offset commit?

Comment: 1) Please limit posts to single questions. 2) Why would you want auto commit enabled? Can you explain your use case

Comment: the default value is true, so, I'm trying to understand, what happens when i leave the default settings.

Comment: Well, you lose data guarantees of delievry and resiliency.

Comment: I would like to think offset commits and polling are different threads. If the consumer rebalances, I'm not really sure if commits continue or not. You're welcome to setup your own monitoring and try it

Comment: Thanks for the details. I'll give a try

Answer (score 0):

im assuming youre asking about the ~modern, java consumer.

> Would it commit only 100 records?

with the exception of sending heartbeats to the broker if youre using consumer group management (the `subscribe()` function), **EVERYTHING** on the consumer happens on the caller thread (your thread) as part of calling `poll()`. this includes committing offsets. this means that no offsets will be sent until you call `poll()`, so in your case the answer is no - offsets would only be committed after youre done with those 500 records.

> If yes is the answer to the above question, what happens to the other records?

answer is no, but in some older clients, where background threads were responsible for auto offset commits, the worse case would have been that if your application crashed it would restore to the position of the 500th record (so you would have skipped over those 400 records you havent processed yet). but again, **this is not the case for modern consumers**

> If no is the answer for the first question, it should commit offset for all the 500 records. Then when does the 'max.poll.interval.ms' come into picture and how does this affect the offset commit?

offset commits and "liveness" are only related if youre using consumer group management (`subscibe()`, not `assign()`). assuming youre using CGM, the kafka cluster needs to determine if a consumer is "alive" or not, and if they think a consumer is dead its work (partitions) is reassigned to another, live consumer. modern kafka defines "liveness" as "making progress", and making progress means youre calling poll "often enough". "often enough" is defined by `max.poll.interval` - so even though there is a heartbeat thread that heartbeats to kafka on a much shorter interval (i think the default is ~3 seconds) if you stop calling poll for 5 minutes that heartbeat thread will stop. more accurately - the heartbeat thread will send a leave group request to kafka and then stop. if youre in that situation (kicked out of the group for lack of progress) any attempt to commit offset by your consumer will fail - kafka only accepts offset commits from live memebers if CGM is used.

this means there's an inherent trade-off between `max.poll.interval` and `max.poll.records` - the bigger the batches of work you `poll()` out of a consumer, the longer it will take until youre done with them and call `poll()` again, the higher your risk of getting kicked out of the group.